# Angular with TypeScript- how do I handle business logic within an observable callback?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to get some data and return something on success using an Angular HttpClient call like this:

```
    return this.http.post('api/my-route', model).subscribe(

        data => (
            this.data = data;
            return $window.location = ReturnUrlService.getAbsolute('/my-other-route');
        )
    )
```

Why can't I do this? My app is Angular 4.3 with TypeScript 2.6.2 My understanding is that the arrow function should be the equivalent of this callback:

```
function(data) {
        this.data = data;
        return $window.location = ReturnUrlService.getAbsolute('/my-other-route');
}
```

... and I'm treating 'data' like it will work as a 'success' callback in JQuery AJAX. Is a subscribe somehow limited to setting values of of properties within the class? What's wrong with my arrow function? I know I'm missing something basic!

Comment: Two remarks: (1) `data => ( ... )` should be replaced with `data => { ... }`, (2) `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` instance (often used to call its `unsubscribe` method), not the value returned by the callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `()` if the "body" is an expression. Your "body" are two statements:

```
return this.http.post('api/my-route', model).subscribe(
    data => (
        this.data = data;
        return $window.location = ReturnUrlService.getAbsolute('/my-other-route');
    )
)
```

Should be:

```
return this.http.post('api/my-route', model).subscribe(
    data => {                                                    // <==== changed this line
        this.data = data;
        return $window.location = ReturnUrlService.getAbsolute('/my-other-route');
    }                                                            // <==== changed this line
)
```

## The `return` statement

It seems you just want to perform the assignment, not return any value. If that's the case, just **remove the `return` keyword** from that last statement.

If, on the other hand, you really do also want to return that value to the caller of that function, don't use [`subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html), but other function that will just transform the `Observable`, [such as `map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html):

```
public myMethod(): Observable<any> {
  // ... create the model variable
  return this.http.post('api/my-route', model).map(
    data => {
        this.data = data;
        return $window.location = ReturnUrlService.getAbsolute('/my-other-route');
    }
  )
}
```

Of course, remember to subscribe to the result wherever you call `myMethod`:

```
public someOtherMethod() {
  return this.myMethod().subscribe(stuff => console.log(stuff));
}
```